# Are UK accounting laws compatible with South African accounting laws?

Tags: united-kingdom, finance

My mother is in South Africa. She has British Passport and would like to return to the UK.

At present, she is a bookkeeper in South Africa but as I understand it, different countries have different laws (financial/accounting).

Would she be able to come to the UK and work without having to complete some training to be able to practice?

Comment: You will do better posting this on workplace.se. Yes the laws are different as are the accounting standards - how different and if this means that her skills are inadequate, I don't know.